# What is happening in this JavaScript ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, cookies, ternary-operator

This function creates & stores a cookie, and here it stores the name of the visitor in a cookie variable. According to the [source](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

> The parameters of the function hold the name of the cookie, the
>   value of the cookie, and the number of days until the cookie expires.
>
> In the function we first convert the number of days to a valid
>   date, then we add the number of days until the cookie should expire.
>   After that we store the cookie name, cookie value and the expiration
>   date in the document.cookie object.

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
  var exdate=new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var c_value=escape(value) + 
              ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
  document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

I can see how the Date works, but what is happening in this part:

```
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";
```

Here is the invoking code:

```
function checkCookie()
{
var username=getCookie("username");
if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
  alert("Welcome again " + username);
  }
else 
  {
  username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
    setCookie("username",username,365);
    }
  }
}
```

I appreciate any tips or advice.

Comment: That's a ternary operator: `(test) ? true part : false part`. If `test` evaluates to true, the expression returns the "true part", otherwise the "false part".

Comment: What arguments are typically passed? Could you show us the invoking code?

Comment: @Cory the line is wrapped - its fine and valid

Comment: Yes the code is here - http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username I'll paste above too

Comment: I will fix the code up there, Thank You So Much!

Comment: @Adel for future reference, w3schools is not a very reputable source for javascript information (such as the incorrect use of null and comparison operators in the example you've given)

Comment: @jbabey - Thank You So Much for the heads-up, very true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line is wrapped, here is the full line :

```
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
```

this means if the `exdays` parameter was not specifed (`exdays==null`) then add blank (`""`) else add `";expires="` plus the date (`exdate`) as a string using [toUTCString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString)

To learn more about cookies [use Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie) instead of [w3schools](http://w3fools.com). This kind of `if` statement is a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 2):

Should it be something like this?

```
var c_value=escape(value) + (exdays==null) ? "True Part" : "False Part";
```

Comment: Too fast replies within just typing those two lines and submitting the answer... Anyways, hope you found the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The false part of the ternary has a line break in it at the very end. I guess it should be this:

```
 var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
```

instead of:

```
 var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; 
     expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
```

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bad line break in your posted code.

```
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; 
  expires="+exdate.toUTCString()); // this line should be up after the semicolon
```

This would then yield:

```
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
```

Which basically means if `exdays` given to the function is null (double equals so it is coerced, which means undefined, empty string, or integer 0 would also fail) then the expiration string would not be concatenated. If an expiration date was given, it would append `";expires="+exdate.toUTCString()` to the cookie string.

Comment: Thank You Very Much Babey! Also for the double equals info too!